# Limit access to proftpd user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, proftpd

I'm trying to limit access of a specific user (Ex. bob) in proftpd. I have some users that can access the entire server, but 1 specific users should be able to access only 2 folders. Have this structure:

```
/var/www/site/
/var/www/site/views/
/var/www/site/assets/
/var/www/site/[more files and folders]
```

I succeeded in giving the user bob a "jailed" access to one of the 2 folders, but not both.

```
DefaultRoot       /var/www/site/views bob
DefaultRoot       / ftpuser
```

This way ftpuser have now unlimited access, and bob can only access `/var/www/site/views`.

How can I give bob access also to `/var/www/site/assets` ??

I tried 2 solution and neither worked:

1. Links

I tried `ls -s /var/www/site/assets /var/www/site/views`. This worked for all users but bob. So I tried:

```
cd /var/www/site/views
ls -s ../assets/ assets
```

Again, the link works to everyone bu bob.

2. Hiding stuff

I tried to make `DefaultRoot /var/www/site/ bob` and then add

```
<Directory /var/www/site/otherdir>
  <Limit ALL>
    DenyUser bob
    AllowAll
  </Limit>
</Directory>
```

This doesn't work at all. Plus, under /var/www/site/ there are other files that should be hidden and that are not directories.

So again, How can I give bob access to both `/var/www/site/assets` and `/var/www/site/views` but nothing else is under `/var/www/site` ??

Comment: Check if your question is covered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789064/how-to-limit-a-users-ssh-access-to-certain-folders

Comment: @Eda: actually is not. The linked questions asked about ssh users. The question I was asking was about FTP users (bob doesn't have ssh access to the server).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set up `/var/www/site/assets` and `/var/www/site/views` as separate filesystems that are mounted in multiple places.

e.g. mount them at their current locations and under `/home/bob/`.

This requires some effort initially but it is likely to be the simplest and most secure solution for your users.

See the **Filesystem Tricks** section in the Proftpd [chroot howto](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Chroot.html).

Comment: can you explain in more details?